# Excel VBA to Connect to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I would just like to ask if Inserting Data to SharePoint using Excel VBA with SQL could be harmful to the SharePoint Farm. Below are the connection string that I used.

Connection String:

```
sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
"DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
"LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID & ";"
```

SQL Query:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO [TableName] (" & colHeaders & ") VALUES (" & colValues & ");"
```

Is this code writing directly into the SharePoint Database or into the List itself?

Comment: You should never write into SharePoint's DB's. You could create a custom DB and do data injection to that. But stay away from SP DB's.

Comment: Could you Share how to a data injection into the SP DB's? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, this code adds and item on a SharePoint list using Excel VBA SQL. Again, thank you so much for answering my post.